# c# console app, break readline(), thread looping?

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application

So I have a method in console app that renders menu and waits for user input:

```
 public void RenderMainMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pick one option:");
        Console.WriteLine("[1] Option1");
        Console.WriteLine("[2] Option2");

        var userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        // ... other code of what do to with user input
    }
```

I also have a class that is being created at the start of an application and this this class is responsible for looping over a list constantly in the background all the time, while application is running:

```
class CheckList
{
    Thread t;
    List<DateTime> list;
    public CheckList()
    {
        list = new List<DateTime> { DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1) };
        t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LoopList));
        t.Start();
    }

    private void LoopList()
    {
        foreach (DateTime d in list)
        {
            if (d >= DateTime.Now)
            {
                // Get out of main menu and display a new menu now.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Is it even possible to achieve such result on Console.App? I mean like:
Having a type of menu (menu1, menu2, menu3) available for you at all times and getting a userInput for it while navigating and doing stuff, but once time comes - some menu pops up and this userInput goes to the new menu that popped up...?

Comment: Try to clearly specify your problem using relevant terms to help others solve your problem. Currently, it is very unclear to understand what you want to do.

Comment: even if its clear enough what you want "best approach" is opinions.. not facts..

Comment: Well I haven't found anything apart just "send enter to the console to break the readline()" - is that the only way? It doesn't seem like the best approach to me, it might be though - who knows i just wanna see what my options are.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling another thread inside the main method. It isn't clear unless you share some code and then we can understand what you are trying to say. Can you please share your source code, so that we can help you out on this ?

```
public class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter any value");
    string str = Console.ReadLine();
    ThreadStart childref = new ThreadStart(CallToChildThread);
    Thread childThread = new Thread(childref);
    childThread.Start();
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
  public static void CallToChildThread()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Child thread starts");

    // the thread is paused for 5000 milliseconds
    int sleepfor = 5000;

    Console.WriteLine("Child Thread Paused for {0} seconds", sleepfor / 1000);
    Thread.Sleep(sleepfor);
    Console.WriteLine("Child thread resumes");
  }
}
```